# Laravel Must be string when saving

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a mounted variable and an error occurs when i'm about to save the variable.

```
   public $code;

   public function mount()
    {
        $this->code = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 5)), 0, 3).Carbon::now()->format('md').rand(100, 999);
    }
```

```
protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'applicant.code' => [
                'string',
                'required',
             ],
        ];
    }
```

blade

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('applicant.code') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="code" hidden>{{ trans('cruds.applicant.fields.code') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" id="code" value="{{ $code }}" disabled hidden>
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('applicant.code') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('cruds.applicant.fields.code_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-indigo mr-2" type="submit">
            {{ trans('global.submit') }}
        </button>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.applicants.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
            {{ trans('global.cancel') }}
        </a>
    </div>
```

> The code must be a string.

I can't seem to figure out this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: The code you shared is not enough to help you, have you dumped the model before saving ? (with `dd()` for example) can you share the rest of the code, from the when the model is defined to the save you performer.

Comment: i'll update the codes above

Comment: i can't put all my codes above since it's too long

Answer (score 0):

```
function mount() {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';    
    $date = date("md");
    $numbers = rand(100, 999); 
   
    $randomString = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($characters, 5)), 0, 3). $date . $numbers;       
      
    return $randomString;
}
echo mount();
```

Comment: how can I convert it to string sir?

Comment: @martinamu carbon output, even if numeric, is a string. Even so, the final value is a concatenation of strings so it is a string in the end. Plus your answer is at best a comment.

Comment: Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', now())->format('md');

Comment: @martin i tried your suggestion but i'm having the same error

Comment: @N69S I have no privileges to send comments yet. You are right. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @N69S any ideas?

Comment: @KrutSednar you're using the mount() method but not rendering the component. i dont know which component that mount() method belongs to so i cant help you. you should read the documentation https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components

Comment: @KrutSednar check now and remove disabled or change it to readonly.

Answer (score 0):

`<input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" id="code" value="{{ $code }}" disabled hidden>`

Your input `code` is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Your rule defines `applicant.code`, therefore the validation is expecting a variable named `applicant` with a key named `code`:

```php
public array $applicant = [
    'code' => null,
];


public function mount()
{
    $this->applicant['code'] = ''; // Implement your code
}
```

Also, you have an input showing the code in your blade view. Is this meant to be editable? If so, you should be using `wire:name` instead of `name` ([See docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding)).

However, since you have it disabled, I don't assume you want to allow the user to edit it, so why have it validated in the first place?